# Ubuntu keeps booting into emergency boot after frequent powercut

Tags: boot, 23.04

Sorry if there's any formatting issue. I'm writing this from my phone.

I am running Ubuntu 23.04 on my system. There was a local issue with my electricity connection for a couple days thus there were frequent voltage changes and powercut in the last 2 days.

After one such powercut, I tried to turn on my pc and it booted straight into emergency mode.

[image]

Here's what I see when I run `journalctl -xb | grep failed`

This is what I see:

[image]

Trying to run fsck manually doesn't work either. Here's what I see after mounting or unmounting the disk.

[image]

Lastly here's what systemctl reboot or default says

[image]

Now I'm clueless on how to troubleshoot or recover it from this point. I'd ideally like to fix ubuntu and boot again without effecting the files in my /home directory which is mounted in /dev/sda5